# How to reuse TestCaseSource from other project

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I am creating component test for backend and UI. 
Created TestCaseSource for backend as a separate library and referring the dll in UI component test solution.

**Component Test for Backend:**

```
[TestCaseSource(nameof(TestDataSourceForIsNeeded))]
    public void VerifyNeeded(string identifier,
        SampDataEventArgs currentState, AvailableInfo expected)
    {
        //Expected
        SampleInfo.Raise(x => x.NewSListData += null,
            currentState);
        Assert.AreEqual(expected.IsNeeded, actual.IsNeeded,
            string.Format("{0} IsNeeded is expected to be {1}", identifier, expected.IsNeeded));
    }
```

**How to reuse the same TestCaseSource from other project**. 
I want to refer the same TestCaseSource for UI test also..net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference the other dll from your UI test assembly and use the form of the attribute that specifies the type...

```
[TestCaseSource(typeof(SomeType), nameof(SomeType.TestDataSourceForIsNeeded)]
```